# Stabilize ffmpeg rtsp to hls transmuxing

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg to convert a RTSP stream (from a security camera) into a HLS stream which I then play on a website using hls.js.

I start the transmuxing with: `ffmpeg -i rtsp:<stream> -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 1 -an -flags -global_header -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_wrap 3 -vcodec copy -y <file>.m3u8`

I can get the stream to play, but the quality isn't good at all... Sometimes the stream jumps on time or freezes for a while. If I open it using VLC I get the same kind of problems.

Any idea why? Or how can I stabilize it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue one time and the issue ended up being not enough bandwidth. Be it an issue with whatever means the camera is using to stream, the connection to the server, etc. In my case, I had a set bandwidth listed as an FFMPEG argument that I simply had to increase. I know sometimes really low framerates set on the camera can cause oddities where you may have to add the "-framerate (Frames Per Second)" argument (no quotes) depending on how the page is set up.

If it is a bandwidth issue, the only way to resolve it as far as I'm aware is to increase the bandwidth somehow or make sure you aren't limiting yourself in some way which could come down to exactly how you are hosting the website/server and verifying speeds from each point the best you can. If you can't find the oddity in the connection yourself or need additional help, comment and I will help further.

This is an old question, so I don't know if OP will see this or not, but I'll leave this here to potentially give something to troubleshoot to anyone else having the same or similar issue since this is what helped me on a very similar issue.